# Python BeautifulSoup - get elements without child elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, html, beautifulsoup

Example HTML:

```
<p class="labels">
  <span>Item1</span>
  <span>Item2</span>
  <time class="time">
    <span>I dont want to get this span</span>
  </time>
</p>
```

I am currently getting all the spans within the tag with the `labels` class, but i just want to get the 2 spans directly under the `labels` class and i dont want to get any `span` tags from child elements.

Currently i am doing it like this obviously:

First i am getting the labels HTML from a much bigger HTML:

```
labels = html.findAll(_class="labels")
```

Then i extract the span tags out of this.

```
spans = labels[0].findAll('span', {"class": None}
```

In my case the `"class": None` doesn't change anything because no span tag has any class.

So my question again is, how can i just get the first 2 span tags without all child elements?

Comment: Couldn't you make a list comprehension that iterates over the direct children of `labels[0]` and grabs any `span`s from there?

Comment: Do you need all `span` tags before `time` tag inside `p` tag ?

Comment: Yes, exactly - and there could be more or less then 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a little sentence in the BeautifulSoup Docs where one can find `recursive = False`

So the answer on this problem was:

```
spans = labels[0].findAll('span', {"class": None}, recursive=False)
```

Answer (score 2):

```py
for container in html.findAll(_class="labels"):
    spans = container.findAll('span', {"class": None})
    spans = [span for span in spans if span.parent is container]
```

Alternatively iterate the [`.children`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#contents-and-children):

```
for container in html.findAll(_class="labels"):
    filter = lambda c: c.name == 'span' and c.class_ == None
    spans = [child for child in container.children if filter(child)]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Tried this, but both solutions return all span tags.

Comment: @Bioaim Please provide a complete code sample that reproduces the problem.

Comment: @Bioaim Nice find! Strange though that my code does not seem to work for you, both samples should return the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

To extract first two span elements try below

```
>>>[i.text for i in html.find('p',{"class":"labels"}).findAll('span', {"class": None})[0:2]]
>>>[u'Item1', u'Item2']
```

If you want to grab all `span` inside class `labels` then remove the slice-

```
>>>[i.text for i in html.find('p',{"class":"labels"}).findAll('span', {"class": None})]
>>>[u'Item1', u'Item2', u'I dont want to get this span']
```

Comment: I think the OP wants "all children that fulfill the condition", not "the first two".

Comment: True, there could be just one span tag or maybe even 3.